# Xcode says my "iPhone has recently restarted" and won't run

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios11, xcode9

I am making an app in Xcode 9.2 and trying to run it on my iPhone (5S running iOS 11.2.1), Xcode compiles the application fine (I can run it in the simulator) but it does not run on my iPhone.

When I try to run it on my iPhone it just says "*iPhone has recently restarted*" and "*Xcode will continue when iPhone is unlocked.*" Now, my phone **has not recently restarted** and I tried unlocking the phone and restarting it but neither works. I also tried restarting Xcode.

Is anyone else getting this "recently restarted" error? Is there anything I can do about it?

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Unpair the device and pair it again from ***xcode -> Window -> Devices*** will solve this issue.

Posted as answer after the confirmation from @brettf.

Comment: This works also for iOS 11.2.5 on Xcode 9.2, but you must disconnect the cable first. Otherwise Xcode will just crash.

Comment: This works also for iOS 11.2.6 on Xcode 9.2, but you must disconnect the cable first. Otherwise Xcode will just crash.

Comment: What if it's connected through Wifi? I've unpaired and now I need a cable to pair again.

Comment: @CanPoyrazoğlu had the same situation, in Xcode -> Window -> Devices disabled 'Connect via network' option and it also solved the issue

Comment: @DimaCheverda so if I disable it there, can I enable it again *without plugging it with a USB cable first*?

Comment: @CanPoyrazoğlu Not sure, the reason to do this is to completely disconnect an iPhone from Xcode

Comment: I faced all your solution, but this last time (Xcode 14.1 macOS ventura) I just restarted Xcode

Comment: In my case disconnecting and connecting again the cable worked.

Answer (score 34):

if you using vpn services, then you need to turn off vpn. It will help

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 13):

If you're using a VPN on your iPhone that may be causing the problem - at least it was for me. Things went back to normal once I turned off my iPhone VPN.

I didn't have a problem while a VPN was enabled on my Mac, but it may be worth turning that off as well if you still have issues when the iOS device VPN is turned off and the device still won't connect correctly.

Comment: Can confirm disabling VPN on device resolves this. The Xcode error alert is misleading. Have submitted FB12061987 to Apple requesting correction.  http://feedbackassistant.apple.com/feedback/12061987

Answer (score 3):

Just to clarify:

1. **Unplug device**
2. In Xcode, windows -> devices and simulators
3. Right-click the device shown in the left pane. Select 'Unpair device'
4. Plug in device
5. Follow the prompts on the iPhone and Mac

Comment: Had this error in Xcode 14.3.1, but for an Apple Watch. These steps fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered this problem for Xcode 12(both release and beta version), the `unpair and repair` solution does not resolve, so I reset all settings(`Settings` -> `General` -> `Reset` -> `Reset All Settings`), and then the problem solved.

Comment: OK but worth mentioning to readers that the reset will completely wipe all device data and settings.