# Xcode 13: Build hangs with "iPhone is busy: making Apple Watch ready for development"

Tags: xcode, watchos

**Issue:** The build hangs with "iPhone is busy: making Apple Watch ready for development"

**Further facts:**

- iOS 14.8
- iPhone 8
- watchOS 7.6.2
- Xcode 13
- Apple Watch Series 3 + Cellular (42mm)

Does anyone know a solution for that issue?

Many of the developers have the same issue:

- https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/691452

Comment: I was able to get past this error by unpairing my Apple Watch.  It's not ideal but it's an option.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I have been struggling with this for some time now. If you don't need the Apple Watch, instead of turning it off completely, you can also turn on **airplane mode** if configured correctly.

**On your watch, go to `Settings App` → `Airplane Mode`. Make sure that both `WIFI` and `Bluetooth` switches are turned off!**

When the bluetooth switch is turned on, a connection will still be established even if your watch is in airplane mode AND bluetooth is turned off on the phone from Control Center. It took me some time to figure this out...

*Update: The Bluetooth setting seems to turn itself on again after some time! No idea why... ‍♂️ Keep that in mind and check the setting again if flight mode does not fix your issue.*

#### Using Flutter?

When running `flutter doctor`, it will give you a clear hint, that your watch is causing the issue.

When trying to build your app e.g. from Android Studio, you might instead find these messages in your log:

```
The requested device could not be found because no available devices matched the request.

Available destinations for the "dev" scheme:
[list of devices]

Could not build the precompiled application for the device.

Building a deployable iOS app requires a selected Development Team with a Provisioning Profile. Please ensure that a Development Team is selected by:
[instructions how to set the development team]

Ineligible destinations for the "dev" scheme:
[list of devices]
```

I put these messages here for people googling them. If you have an Apple Watch, then run `flutter doctor` to check if this is the root cause.

Comment: Best answer. Thank you. No idea why it hangs at that point... Apple should fix it..

Comment: Love it,.. even 10 years later, this isn't properly fixed. Unbelievable, but thanks to this hint, I don't have to unpair it all the time.

Comment: Was having the same issue and just straight up turning off my watch solved the issue. Thanks!

Comment: Not sure how this can be a solution, really. A terrible workaround at best. I do actually want my watch to keep functioning, that's why I wear it.

Comment: I fully agree, but it seems that there is no proper solution until Apple fixes it. This is at least the easiest "temporary solution"...

Comment: I am using flutter and had an apple personal apple watch (I don't develop for it) and could not work out for the life of me why nothing would build.  This worked in the end.

Answer (score 16):

This is what works for me:

1. Turn off the Bluetooth from settings in your iPhone from **Settings -> Bluetooth** (*Don't turn it off from the control center*)
2. Quit Xcode
3. Launch it again
4. Build and Run

Comment: Turning off Bluetooth on the Watch works best for me.  I'd rather leave the iPhone BT on.   I don't have to quit Xcode (13.3), just turn off Bluetooth on Watch and build again works.

Comment: @progrmr I haven't tested it yet but it seems to be a better solution, awesome.

Comment: For me helped rebooting AppleWatch.

Answer (score 5):

The solution is:

- Waiting for 5-20 mins
- Let your iPhone and Apple Watch on

Comment: That's not entirely true. If you don't need the watch you can just power off the Apple Watch and unplug/plug the iPhone. That's a quick fix

Answer (score 5):

I facing this issue too. This is because the latest xcode only support until iOS 15.2 sdk, but my phone's iOS version is 15.3. Thus, xcode is downloading the iOS 15.3 sdk from your phone that's why takes time *(I knew the message is not saying that)*

However, I do some testing and it works for me.

- Get the iOS 15.3 sdk (is 10BG!!!) from my friend xcode's Devices Support iOS folder `/Users/XXX/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport` and paste it to yours one.
- Downloading the iphone OS device support file from https://github.com/filsv/iPhoneOSDeviceSupport/blob/0e8ef7bc51b982304ed3258454f88ae2d5615ac7/15.3.zip unzip it and paste it in `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport`
- Restart Xcode.
- Build success without waiting.

Origin From: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/691452?answerId=704424022#704424022

Answer (score 4):

I think all answers are overlooked, you don't need 5-20 mins if you let it finish the preparing process, it'll take just a few minutes, 5 mins top..
But regarding fixing this with an upgrade, that's not the case, and I would love to see it fixed, or offered with an option to exclude watch from the dev purpose unless really needed.

Comment: It takes 20 minutes for me. I just timed it, twice.

Answer (score 4):

The Apple Watch configuration takes around 5 minutes. It's way better to postpone everything and let it run for 5 minutes then the other workarounds - such as disconnecting your watch, turning on/off your iphone, etc

Comment: I absolutely agree fixing the issue preventing the watches configuration is much more worthwhile than all those upvoted or even accepted answers saying to disconnect the watch, disabling much of its functionality.

Comment: I had to wait about two hours, but solved the problem :-)

Comment: It's not about 5 minutes. I've waited for 2.5 hours 

Answer (score 2):

In my case:
If my Apple Watch is turned on - then from Xcode I'm still able build and run the app just fine.
But when I'm using Flutter - it fails.
`flutter devices` shows my iphone as "Busy".

As soon as I turn off the Apple Watch, and then disconnect and reconnect the iPhone USB cable - all is good.

Since it's one of the earliest Apple Watch modules, the latest WatchOS that I can install is v6.3, although the latest available is WatchOS v8.x.

I suppose this issue doesn't occur with the latest WatchOS.
(I'm using iOS v15.2)

Comment: Same thing happened to me. Solution was to power off the watch!

Comment: Selling the Watch worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

This still happens from time to time. The solution that has worked for me every time is to reboot the phone

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're running a version of Xcode that supports the SDK versions of your iOS/watchOS device. If you've recently updated either OS versions, you may need a matching Xcode update for this to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Could also be that your device firmware isn't compatible with your version of Xcode.

For example, iOS 16.4 was released yesterday (28th March 2023). My version of Xcode is 14.2 - which is the latest production version. There was supposed to be a new production build of Xcode (14.3), but the latest is an RC2 build - so Xcode doesn't have support for my iOS version.

Try unpairing/pairing your device first.

If the above applies to you, you can manually add support - check out this Github repo:

https://github.com/iGhibli/iOS-DeviceSupport

Answer (score 0):

What fixed this for me in Xcode 14.3.1 was to unpair the iPhone in Xcode, then reconnect it (following these instructions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51778221)

Answer (score -1):

The real solution is:
If you don't need the apple watch you can just power off the Apple Watch and unplug/plug the iPhone. That's a quick fix. No need to unpair the watch no need to wait 5 - 20 mins

Comment: No need to power off Watch, just turn off Bluetooth on Watch.

Comment: Need Apple Watch, but neen't develop app for Apple Watch. If power off the Apple Watch, cannot get phone or messege from the Watch.

Comment: @progrmr just turning off Bluetooth never worked to me. Maybe going complete Airplane mode (without wifi) but even that didn’t work for me. My solution always was: turn off the watch, run the project the turn on the watch again.

Answer (score -7):

According to this post, this issue is fixed with an upgrade to iOS 15.0.2 / watchOS 8.0.1: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/691452

Comment: It's not fixed even in iOS 15.1.1

Comment: Nor in 15.2 ...

Comment: Nor does it work in 15.2.1

Comment: Not in 15.3.1...

Comment: Not fixed in 15.4

Comment: Still not fixed in 15.6